# Navigation drawer does not open when pressing the hamburger icon in toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to toggle the navigation view by the hamburger icon. The navigation view is appearing on sliding from the left. The following is the code that I have included in my MainActivity "onCreate Function"

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();
```

I also have tried this code block which doesn't seem to work.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I also tried this

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);  // OPEN DRAWER
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

My main_activity.xml is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    >

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_bar"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_bar"
            app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is my app_bar_main.xml which is where I define the ui of toolbar.

```
    enter code here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.android.moodindigo.MainActivity">

    <!--<RelativeLayout-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/relativelayout_for_fragment"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
    <!--&gt;</RelativeLayout>-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="Mood Indigo"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please let me know if anything else is needed. I didn't paste the whole code here as the project is quite big. I checked many StackOverflow post for this and I tried to do the same thing but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your post still lacks the description of the problem. "Hamburger icon not working". Does it mean that it's not visible? What specifically is wrong?

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);` Remove this piece of code. It messes up with `ActionBarDrawerToggle`

Comment: On pressing the hamburger Icon. The navigation drawer is not opening. But the navigation drawer is opening on sliding from the left. I'll edit the question title.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the existing code but here's a workaround. Set a listener on `toggle` using `toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(...)`, and then handle the click events in the `onClick()` function in the listener. See if you can make any Toast/Log there. If that works then just open the drawer from there using `drawer.openDrawer(...)`

Comment: You need to have only one `View` that is not the drawer inside your `<DrawerLayout>`. As you have it now, the `<RelativeLayout>` is covering the `Toolbar` `<include>`. Both of those things need to be inside one single `ViewGroup`, so you could move the `<include>` into the `<RelativeLayout>`, or move the `<RelativeLayout>` into `content_main`, or whatever way you want to get those all in one.

Comment: @MikeM. Tried. Moved toolbar to `<RelativeLayout>`. Not Working.

Comment: That's not very descriptive. Are you sure something isn't still covering it? `RelativeLayout` can overlap `View`s, depending on your layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this in the onCreate of your main activity :

```
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

i hope it will help you!

Comment: Tried. Not working. Replaced setDrawerListener(toggle) with addDrawerListener(toggle) because the prior one is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

In your ActionBarDrawerToggle constructor you use **toolbar** as third parameter. I am not sure if it is valid, since the official documentation for ActionBarDrawerToggle constructor parameters quotes:

> Parameters:
>
> activity - Activity: the Activity hosting the drawer
>
> drawerLayout - Drawerlayout: the DrawerLayout to link to the given Activity's
>   ActionBar
>
> drawerImageRes - int: A Drawable resource to use as the drawer
>   indicator
>
> openDrawerContentDescRes - int: A String resource to describe the
>   "open drawer" action for accessibility
>
> closeDrawerContentDescRes - int: A String resource to describe the
>   "close drawer" action for accessibility

So, the third parameter should be Drawable Resource but **toolbar** is a View.

**Edit:**
As you are using v7 and not v4, there is one sentence from official documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html I think is important:

> Please use ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity, DrawerLayout, int, int) if you are setting the Toolbar as the ActionBar of your activity.

So it seems you should use differnt constructor from the one you are using now.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Ya, you are correct. It is true in `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` but I am using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` in which it has to be toolbar. I changed it to v4 and it shows `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is deprecated. These different libraries for the same thing are pretty confusing.